# Wordpress - How to change the color of the Username displayed after user is logged in?

Tags: css, wordpress, authentication

When user is logged in, WP-Members says: You are logged in as "username". How to refer this username in the CSS in order to change its color?

Answer (score 0):

In your theme file:

```
<?php

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    ?>
    <p class="loggedin">You are logged in as "username".</p>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <p class="loggedout">You are logged in as "username".</p>
    <?php
}

?>
```

The CSS

```
p.loggedin {
    color: green;
}

p.loggedout {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work :( It only adds one more text raw in the same color "You are logged in as "username"."

I am using WP-Members and this is the text that appears in the sidebar, after the user is logged.

Also, as it is called automatically, it takes the "username" somehow, I am interested in this somehow - how it is called so that i can call and simply change its color in the CSS. Isn't it possible to have this simple solution? What is the shortcode for the username in WP?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to filter it.  There is a filter hook for the sidebar logged in status - [wpmem_sidebar_status](http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/users-guide/filter-hooks/wpmem_sidebar_status/).  The string of HTML for the sidebar status is passed to the filter.  That would be like this:

```
<p>You are logged in as username<br />
<a href="http://logoutlink">click here to log out</a>
```

So if you want to apply some CSS to the username to style it, you need something to define.  What you need to do is wrap the username in a span tag. But how can you do that?

`str_replace` will do a search and replace on a specific string or an array of strings. So we can replace the text before the username with that text **plus** an opening span wrapper.  We can replace the `<br />` tag with the closing span tag **plus** the `<br />` tag.

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_sidebar_status', 'my_sidebar_status' );

function my_sidebar_status( $string ) {

    /** The original pieces **/
    $old = array(
        'You are logged in as',
        '<br />',
    );

    /** The replacements **/
    $new = array(
        'You are logged in as <span class="my_class">',
        '</span><br />',
    );

    /** Do the search/replace **/
    $new_string = str_replace( $old, $new, $string );

    /** Return the filtered result **/
    return $new_string;
}
```

This filter doing the replacement described would result in the sidebar status output being this:

```
<p>You are logged in as <span class="my_class">username</span><br />
<a href="http://logoutlink">click here to log out</a>
```

Then you could apply some CSS to the .my_class class

```
.my_class {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```